# Get selected option data using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to get the selected option data whose option value is known. I have the selected option value and I want the data which is wrapped between the option.

For example in the following select:

```
<select name="oi_report_contact[sex]" id="oi_report_contact_sex">
       <option value="1">Male</option>
       <option value="2">Female</option>
       <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>
```

I have value 1, I need to get the data "Male" through Jquery or Javascript.

Please note : `$('#oi_report_contact_sex').val();` will give 1 and not male, when 1 is selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to call

```
var content = $('#oi_report_contact_sex option:selected').html();
```

to get the inner content of the selected option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.text()` method to get the text value. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BdzVQ/1/).

```
$('#oi_report_contact_sex').on('change', function () {
  alert($('#oi_report_contact_sex').val());
  alert($('#oi_report_contact_sex option:selected').text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
          $("#oi_report_contact_sex").find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$("#oi_report_contact_sex option[value='" + $("#oi_report_contact_sex").val() + "']").text()
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ARBb2/1/